# How to specify long string literals in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to conveniently store long string literal in Visual Basic source?
I'm composing a console application with `--help` printout let's say 20 lines long.

Most welcome would be to have raw text area somewhere in source code where I can manage
output text 1:1. Many languages supply HEREDOC functionality. In the VB, I couldn't find it.
But maybe this could be tricked somehow via LINQ (XML)?

Thank you for good tips in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update:

In VB.NET 14, which comes with Visual Studio 2015, [all string literals support multiple lines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2014/12/09/new-language-features-in-visual-basic-14.aspx).  In VB.NET 14, all string literals work like *verbatim* string literals in C#.  For instance:

```
Dim longString = "line 1
line 2
line 3"
```

---

### Original Answer:

c# has a handy multi-line-string-literal syntax using the `@` symbol (called *verbatim strings*), but unfortunately VB.NET does not have a direct equivalent to that (*this is no longer true--see update above*).  There are several other options, however, that you may still find helpful.

### Option 1: Simple Concatenation

```
Dim longString As String =
    "line 1" & Environment.NewLine &
    "line 2" & Environment.NewLine &
    "line 3"
```

Or the less .NET purist may choose:

```
Dim longString As String =
    "line 1" & vbCrLf &
    "line 2" & vbCrLf &
    "line 3"
```

### Option 2: String Builder

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
builder.AppendLine("line 1")
builder.AppendLine("line 2")
builder.AppendLine("line 3")
Dim longString As String = builder.ToString()
```

### Option 3: XML

```
Dim longString As String = <x>line 1
line 2
line 3</x>.Value
```

### Option 4: Array

```
Dim longString As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, {
    "line 1",
    "line 2",
    "line 3"})
```

### Other Options

You may also want to consider other alternatives.  For instance, if you really want it to be a literal in the code, you could do it in a small c# library of string literals where you could use the `@` syntax.  Or, you may decide that having it in a literal isn't really necessary and storing the text as a string resource would be acceptable.  Or, you could also choose to store the string in an external data file and load it at run-time.

Comment: You've missed the continuation character from the end of your lines - append a space and underscore after the ampersands and also on the end of the assignment (i.e. `Dim longString As String = _` and `"line 1" & vbCrLf & _`).

Comment: VB will now infer line continuation under those circs

Comment: nitpicking: some of your options are not string *literals*, though. Also, xml literals have nothing to do linq :-)

Comment: @Westie As peterG said, you don't need those any more in most cases.  As long as it's clear that you are in the middle of a statement, it is able to automatically infer that the statement continues on the next line.  It doesn't hurt to still include the line continuation characters, just to be explicit, but not having them cluttering up your code is nice too :)

Comment: @DominicKexel, granted, but they do all *include* literals :)  Thanks for the clarification on the XML-literal option.

Comment: @StevenDoggart - Thanks for that; nice to know. peterG - Inference gets everywhere these days! ;o)

Comment: @Westie More importantly (but widely unknown) since Visual Studio 2010 SP1, you can omit the `ByVal` keyword in method declarations.

Comment: @Westie – to bring clarity into implicit line continuation, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865x40k4.aspx) article covers _all_ cases – please scroll to **Implicit Line Continuation** section.

Comment: At the moment, **Option 3: XML** looks the best for keeping and maintaining text 1:1. But thank you for all of them.

Comment: @miroxlav - That's going to be useful.

Comment: Thx. 3rd option as XML ... very nice!

Comment: Just read over the VB.NET 14 link, and all I can say is "YES, FOR THE LOVE OF GOD, YES". thanks for the update.

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply use a text resource (Project -> Properties -> Resources) and access them in your code via `My.Resources.NameOfTheResource`.

Comment: Thanks for adding this option for greater coverage of this question.

In my case I would prefer text inserted _directly in the source code file_ as I wrote in the question, but mentioning resources here is still good for reference.

Comment: @miroxlav * I would prefer text inserted directly in the source code file*: Then I would suggest using XML literals, as these are the least clunky method to do this IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.net you can simply write "& _" at the end of your string literal to have multi-line strings.

Comment: That wouldn't make the strings multi-line--it would only make the literals multi-line.

Comment: @MansoorShaikh - `vbCrLf` is exactly that (i.e. a string constant CR and LF), and is a passed down from old VB6, whereas `NewLine` is more platform independant (in a very small nutshell).