# Writing a SQL statement while declaring variables

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to write a SQL statement in a VB application. In this case, I need to declare two variables to call other stored procedures. This code works when I run it in SSMS, but I am not sure how to do it in VB.

Statement:

```
DECLARE @NewIncidentNoteId NVARCHAR(15)
EXEC uspGetNextId @NewIncidentNoteId OUTPUT

INSERT INTO [dbo].[IncidentNotes]
           ([Id]
           ,[IncidentId]
           ,[TaskId]
           ,[VLevel]
           ,[NotesSourceType]
           ,[Notes]
           ,[LogDate]
           ,[LogTime]
           ,[LogTZ]
           ,[LogBy]
           ,[LogByName]
           ,[NotifyFlg]
           ,[ActivityDate]
           ,[ActivityTime]
           ,[ShowInReport])
        VALUES()
           (@NewIncidentNoteId
           ,'60Z3M'
           ,''
           ,'1'
           ,'EIRInvestigatorComment'
           ,'This is a TEST note.'
           ,'20150416'
           ,'10:10:10'
           ,'UTC'
           ,'12876'
           ,'USER, ADMIN'
           ,'False'
           ,'20150416'
           ,'12:13:13'
           ,'1'))
```

Comment: I'm confused.  What are you having trouble with?  What do you want the VB code to do?

Comment: How to write it into an string in VB.

Comment: You just want to know how to take that entire bit of SQL script and declare it as a literal string in VB?

Comment: First question, `Why write it into a string when you can call the SP from VB` this doesn't make sense at all. Your going to have more issue's doing this and more prone to `SQL Injection`...

Comment: Turn that into a procedure and call it from VB.

Comment: @StevenDoggart - Yes

Comment: @SeanLange - The procedure would have to be housed on a third party vendors DB, so I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: I would argue that this kind of thing belongs in the database, not the application. If you are determined to keep this in your application you need to declare a string and then execute it. Be careful though, you need to parameterize your query to avoid sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: @StevenDoggart - I agree, the problem is I don't know how to do that. Looking for some help with it.

Comment: None of the examples on the web that you can find by googling were any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as others have said, the best option would be to actually add it to the database as a stored procedure.  Then you could just execute the stored procedure via a simple ADO.NET command.  However, if you insist on sending the entire SQL script as a command, there are several ways to get it as a string.

VB doesn't currently have great support for multi-line string literals (long-overdue support for that is being added in [VB.NET 14](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2014/12/09/new-language-features-in-visual-basic-14.aspx) as part of Visual Studio 2015).  There are several workarounds.  See [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510717/1359668) for some good options.  However, for something like this, you may want to look into reading the script from an embedded resource or an external script file.

Comment: Interesting how a question that sparked this much discussion was down voted

Answer (score -1):

```
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
 cmd.ActiveConnection = con
 cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
 cmd.CommandText = "empdetails"

 cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter_
    ("empid", adVarChar, adParamInput, 6, str_empid)

 Set rs = cmd.Execute

 If Not rs.EOF Then
  txt_firstname = rs.Fields(0)
  txt_title = rs.Fields(1)
  txt_address = rs.Fields(2)
 End If
```

Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing

this code show how to use SP in vb6 not sure which vb you use if it is VB.net then you can use ADO.net to do that

this link might be helpful too 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15222/How-to-Use-Stored-Procedures-in-VB

Comment: The OP specified VB.NET in the tags